# To get specific part of a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

```
string a = "abc,xyz,wer";
```

Now, I need a part of this string like

```
string b = "abc";
```

I need everything before the first comma.How shall I get it?

Comment: This is to vague. you can use String.Substring, of String.Split. you need to clear this up a little. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members(v=VS.90).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=VS.90).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: what is the criteria for your "part"? is it the first three letter? or first item if the list?

Comment: i need everything before the first comma.

Comment: then please be specific in the question and you can find the answer below.

Comment: @doesdos: In future, please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints so you can ask better questions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Something like this?

```
string b = a.Split(',')[0];
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx):

```
string b = a.Substring(0,3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is vague (are you always looking for the *first* part?), but you can get the exact output you asked for with `string.Split`:

```
string[] substrings = a.Split(',');
b = substrings[0];
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Output:

> abc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the strings separated by the `,` you can use

```
string b = a.Split(',')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid getting expections at run time , do something like this.

There are chances of having empty string sometimes,

```
string a = "abc,xyz,wer";
string b=string.Empty;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a ))
{
  b = a.Split(',')[0];
}
```